# How to Upload and download files to mainframe in .NET without using third party utility or tool?

Tags: .net, upload, ftp, download, mainframe

I use a third party utility for mainframe FTP (like downloading and uploading files) in .NET. Is there a way to do it without any separate utility?

Answer (score 3):

if you want a pure .net libery then on msdn you can read:

> The .NET Framework provides comprehensive support for the FTP protocol
>   with the FtpWebRequest and FtpWebResponse classes. These classes are
>   derived from WebRequest and WebResponse. In most cases, the WebRequest
>   and WebResponse classes provide all that is necessary to make the
>   request, but if you need access to the FTP-specific features exposed
>   as properties, you can typecast these classes to FtpWebRequest or
>   FtpWebResponse.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718.aspx)

**EDIT**

The I would read this:

[An FtpClient Class and WinForm Control](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/client/an-ftpclient-class-and-winform-control)

Comment: thanks for answering my question but in the FTPWebRequest we can just copy the content to pre build file on mainframe , we cannot create the file there on node and there is also an issue in for code conversion. So is there anyway to use FTP as we do in command prompt